# 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, key

I actualy try to create a database but i have an error with the foreign key. Can you hepl me please ?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `City`;
CREATE TABLE  `City` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idCountry` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Name` char(35) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`CountryCode` char(3) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`District` char(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `fk_constraint_city_country` (`idCountry`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_constraint_city_country` FOREIGN KEY (`idCountry`) 
 REFERENCES `Country` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4080 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have this error:  MySQL said: Documentation
1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Can you post the country table schema? Maby id from "country" table it's not the same type as idCountry from "city"table

Comment: Foreign key needs to refer to column from a **table**, which you havent provided in `FOREIGN KEY (idCountry)`

Comment: there is the country table shema:

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Country`;
CREATE TABLE  `Country` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Code` char(3) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`Name` char(52) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Continent` enum('Asia','Europe','North   
 America','Africa','Oceania','Antarctica','South America') CHARACTER SET    
 latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Asia',
`Region` char(26) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`SurfaceArea` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`IndepYear` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`LifeExpectancy` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
`GNP` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`GNPOld` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`LocalName` char(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`GovernmentForm` char(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`HeadOfState` char(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`Capital` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Code2` char(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=240 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and there is the country langage:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CountryLanguage`;
CREATE TABLE  `CountryLanguage` (
`idCountry` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`idLanguage` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`IsOfficial` enum('T','F') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F',
`Percentage` float(4,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`idCountry`,`idLanguage`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `fk_constraint_Language` (`idLanguage`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_constraint_Country` FOREIGN KEY (`idCountry`) REFERENCES    
 `Country` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_constraint_Language` FOREIGN KEY (`idLanguage`)    
 REFERENCES `Language` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf
```